# Webpack ChunkLoadError - The chunks exists and fetched correctly, but somehow they are failing

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Until now, we had a single-page react app which was creating a single file that included all of our code. Over time, the size of the generated file has increased, which introduced a few permformance issues and we are trying to solve them. The logical step for us is to introduce some code splitting and lazy-load some compoennts, but it seems that whenever we are trying to use a dynamic import, webpack fails with a ChunkLoadError.

A few other similar stack overflow questions mention that the issue may be on the publichPath in the webpack configuration. I tried a few options, but still, I get the same error.

I don't think the error is related with the pubichPath configuration because I can access the chunks from my static server. In addition, the network call in the dev tools is also successful.

[image]

Surprisingly, when I reload the page, a chunk that was failing before is loading now. I am not sure how to explain that, but when the app loads for the first time, chunks that are part of the current view are loaded okay. When I navigate to a new page with some additional chunks that I need to load in demand, at that point the app fails again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, have you managed to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, try updating the value of globalObject from 'this' to 'globalThis'(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject). By default, webpack will create a stack in the window object(called webpackChunkwebpack by default) and push each chunk in it. When it tries to access a chunk, it will use what you set in globalObject in order to access the stack. For example, By default, it will this.webpackChunkwebpack, but if this is somehow overridden, the it won't find the chunk. Using globalThis, it ensures that it will access the window object in the browser. @MatheusCastro